# Why is $x = y + 1$ or $x = y - 1$ not antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I stumbled across this question about relation from *Discrete Mathematics and Its Application* (8th Ed.) by Kenneth Rosen as follow:

7. Determine whether the relation R on the set of all integers is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive, where $(x, y) ∈ R$ if and only if 
   c.) $x = y + 1 \; or \; x = y − 1$ (Answer from the book: symmetric only)

Based on my understanding on antisymmetric definition as follow: 
$∀x∀y(((x, y) ∈ R ∧ (y, x) ∈ R) \to (x = y))$

Since there exists no $(x, y)$ and $(y, x)$ that can make the case true, isn't it antisymmetric in this case for the question?

Comment: Hint: rephrase it as $|x-y|=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given condition is $x=y+1$ **or** $x=y-1$. So, it is *not* antisymmetric: $1\mathrel R2$ and $2\mathrel R1$, but $1\ne2$.

Comment: I got the idea thanks to @J.G. hint at the comment. Much appreciated!